# При перезагрузке VS Code сбивается терминал с Git Bash на PowerShell. Как исравить?

Tags: консоль, visual-studio-code

По умолчанию стоит терминал Git Bash. Открывая новую вкладку терминала запускается  Git Bash.
Но после перезагрузки VS Code активный терминал PowerShell.

```
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "PowerShell": {
      "source": "PowerShell",
      "icon": "terminal-powershell"
    },
    "Git Bash": {
      "source": "Git Bash",
      "path": ["C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"],
      "icon": "terminal-bash"
    }
  },
  "terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled": true,
  "terminal.integrated.allowChords": false,
  "terminal.integrated.automationShell.osx": "",
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash",
  "terminal.explorerKind": "external",
  "terminal.integrated.tabs.showActiveTerminal": "singleTerminal"
```

Answer (score 0):

Тоже столкнулся с этой проблемой т.к. узнал что параметр `terminal.integrated.shell.windows` устарел. Пытался настроить по новым стандартам, но никак не получалось настроить так, чтобы при включении сразу был Git Bash. В итоге я добавил и новые параметры и оставил старый добрый, но уже почему-то устаревший `terminal.integrated.shell.windows`.

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
  "PowerShell": null,
  "Command Prompt": null,
  "Git Bash": {
    "source": "Git Bash",
    "path": ["C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"],
    "icon": "terminal-bash"
  }
},
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash",
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
```